# Does index_id=0 in sys.indexes refer to the table itself?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, data-dictionary

Unfortunately the BOL is a little vague on this, but `index_id = 0` on `sys.indexes` or `sys.partitions` appears to refer to the table itself where there is no clustered index on the table.  True - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does index_id=0 in sys.indexes refer
>   to the table itself?

No, For heap based tables it will always exist and it refers to the IAM (Index Allocation Map). For tables with clustered indexes it will not exist.

Notice the "type_desc" is HEAP on these indexes, there is a really good blog entry about the [Index Allocation Map](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/06/24/645803.aspx).

So, Heap tables (ones with no clustered index) will always have one index with entry `index_id = 0`, and tables with clustered indexes will always have an entry with `index_id = 1`.