# How to fetch the row count for all tables in a SQL SERVER database

Tags: sql, sql-server, rowcount

I am searching for a SQL Script that can be used to determine if there is any data (i.e. row count) in any of the tables of a given database.

The idea is to re-incarnate the database in case there are any rows existing (in any of the database).

The database being spoken of is Microsoft SQL Sserver.

Could someone suggest a sample script?

Comment: A nice article discussing different approaches: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/02/count-number-rows-table-sql-server/

Answer (score 463, accepted):

The following SQL will get you the row count of all tables in a database:

```
CREATE TABLE #counts
(
    table_name varchar(255),
    row_count int
)

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable @command1='INSERT #counts (table_name, row_count) SELECT ''?'', COUNT(*) FROM ?'
SELECT table_name, row_count FROM #counts ORDER BY table_name, row_count DESC
DROP TABLE #counts
```

The output will be a list of tables and their row counts.

If you just want the total row count across the whole database, appending:

```
SELECT SUM(row_count) AS total_row_count FROM #counts
```

will get you a single value for the total number of rows in the whole database.

Comment: great, works as described (though takes a while), also good as I'm not allowed to run the reports, thanks

Comment: Have upvoted this - but think it important to mention that `sp_MSForEachTable` is an undocumented proc - afaik, this means that MS does not support it and may remove it from future versions without notice?

Comment: @MarkD Yes, that is correct, although it has been there for several versions of SQL Server without change.

Comment: also, this will do a full table scan on all tables in the database, so running it on a production server will cause 'a bit' of disk io.

Comment: Thank you for this quite elegant solution.
Only one minor issue:
The order clause (ORDER BY table_name, row_count DESC) is a bit strange. When the result is sorted by the table name, it does not make much sense to include the row count column as the second sort column.
Since each table must have a unique name in a MS SQL database, there can never be two rows in the result that have an identical values in the table_name column, therefore the sorting by the row_count column is  meaningless.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in MS SQL 2012. The command seems to run fine, but the resulting query on the #counts table is empty (zero rows).

Comment: Doesn't work on 2016, 'sp_MSForEachTable' doesn't exist.

Comment: @AlanB: `sp_MSForEachTable` is still there in SQL Server 2016, I've just tried it.

Comment: Try this you don't need to create temp table and then drop it. SELECT T.name AS [TABLE NAME], I.rows AS [ROWCOUNT] 
    FROM   sys.tables AS T 
       INNER JOIN sys.sysindexes AS I ON T.object_id = I.id 
       AND I.indid < 2 
ORDER  BY I.rows DESC

Comment: Tried it, works on SQL Server 2017 as well.
@MarkD - in theory you're right, in practice it's efficient and good enough. If MS removes it in the future, we'll resort to something else. Remember it's not for production use anyway, so there's virtually no issue.

Comment: @AndrewHill - of course, it goes without saying

Comment: @RoG - guess it's a permission issue. The feature works.

Comment: @AlanB - guess it's a permission issue. The feature works.

Comment: This works.  But, I was unsuccessful at implementing it with a linked database.

Comment: @AlanB Very late comment, I know, but for anyone out there, also make sure the server does not have a case-sensitive collation - for example, sp_msforeachtable would not be found on a case-sensitive server.

Comment: Can you not do this via a CTE and avoid the ugly temp table creation/deletion?

Answer (score 243):

If you want to by pass the time and resources it takes to count(*) your 3million row tables.  Try this per SQL SERVER Central by Kendal Van Dyke.

---

Row Counts Using sysindexes 
If you're using SQL 2000 you'll need to use sysindexes like so:

```
-- Shows all user tables and row counts for the current database 
-- Remove OBJECTPROPERTY function call to include system objects 
SELECT o.NAME,
  i.rowcnt 
FROM sysindexes AS i
  INNER JOIN sysobjects AS o ON i.id = o.id 
WHERE i.indid < 2  AND OBJECTPROPERTY(o.id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0
ORDER BY o.NAME
```

If you're using SQL 2005 or 2008 querying sysindexes will still work but Microsoft advises that sysindexes may be removed in a future version of SQL Server so as a good practice you should use the DMVs instead, like so:

```
-- Shows all user tables and row counts for the current database 
-- Remove is_ms_shipped = 0 check to include system objects 
-- i.index_id < 2 indicates clustered index (1) or hash table (0) 
SELECT o.name,
  ddps.row_count 
FROM sys.indexes AS i
  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON i.OBJECT_ID = o.OBJECT_ID
  INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ddps ON i.OBJECT_ID = ddps.OBJECT_ID
  AND i.index_id = ddps.index_id 
WHERE i.index_id < 2  AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0 ORDER BY o.NAME
```

Comment: Ok, the script works but requires a "use DB" at the beginning of it.  So, while it works as-is, it was misleading.

Comment: On my database, the accepted answer takes 10 seconds. *This* answer takes 0! +1 for you Keng. Though I did add `JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id` and included s.Name to see the qualified table names.

Comment: Note that using sysindexes or dm_dp_partition_stats will give you an **approximation** of the number of rows!

Comment: Make sure you use the right DB - if you select master 05/08 query will come back blank.
I would suggest adding "USE  [enter your db name here]" to the top of that query in the answer.

Comment: The row_count values might not always reflect the exact current count of rows. For example, when a transaction is rolled back, the row_count value might not be updated immediately. In such situations, you might need to manually update the statistics to reflect the accurate row counts.

Answer (score 153):

Works on Azure, doesn't require stored procs.

```
SELECT t.name       AS table_name
       ,s.row_count AS row_count
FROM   sys.tables t
JOIN   sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
  ON t.OBJECT_ID = s.OBJECT_ID
 AND t.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
 AND t.name NOT LIKE '%dss%' --Exclude tables created by SQL Data Sync for Azure.
 AND s.index_id IN (0, 1)
ORDER  BY table_name;
```

[Credit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arunrakwal/archive/2012/04/09/sql-azure-list-of-tables-with-record-count.aspx).

Comment: What's "AND t.name not like '%dss%'" accomplish?

Comment: @quillbreaker: excluding tables created by SQL Azure Data Sync

Comment: This worked great. I sat back and said "this might take a while" and it was done in two seconds. Was dealing with a 528 table database and had no idea how large it actually was

Comment: This worked fine on SQL Server 2016; Not required this '%dss%'

Comment: Beautiful, as @trench exclaimed,  I was a bit scary, running and querying some command, on production, with hundreds of million records each, in several tables.. but it just went by in a jiffy _on Azure database_ . Thnx Very handy...

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! how can I execute this for the entire sever with about 100+ databases?

Comment: requires `VIEW DATABASE PERFORMANCE STATE` permission

Comment: I'm getting multipe rows per table with 0s for some.

Answer (score 73):

This one looks better than the others I think.

```
USE  [enter your db name here]
GO

SELECT      SCHEMA_NAME(A.schema_id) + '.' +
        --A.Name, SUM(B.rows) AS 'RowCount'  Use AVG instead of SUM
          A.Name, AVG(B.rows) AS 'RowCount'
FROM        sys.objects A
INNER JOIN sys.partitions B ON A.object_id = B.object_id
WHERE       A.type = 'U'
GROUP BY    A.schema_id, A.Name
GO
```

Comment: +1: this query just requires `data_reader` permissions.

Comment: I don't know why but this query doesn't count rows in all tables accurately. Counts in some tables are doubled. I found Rikin Patel's query to be accurate.

Comment: @Dan The difference between this one and the one by Rikin Patel is that this one is not checking that the index_id of the sys.partitions entry is either 0 or 1. So it isn't just that some rows are doubled, it is that some rows are multiplied by the number of indexes they have. So if you have a table with 100 rows in it and you've defined 3 indexes on it, the above query would show 3*100=300 rows for that table.

Comment: The comments above are valid - but all I needed was to understand which tables had _some_ rows in and which had none.  I only had `data_reader` permissions, so none of the other solutions worked for me - only this one.

Answer (score 31):

Short and sweet

```sql
sp_MSForEachTable 'DECLARE @t AS VARCHAR(MAX); 
SELECT @t = CAST(COUNT(1) as VARCHAR(MAX)) 
+ CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + ''?'' FROM ? ; PRINT @t'
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:**
This query may be resource-intensive if the database is very large. (As per comment)

Comment: Years later, this one worked perfectly for a quick look at how many rows each of your tables have on SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Years after that comment... this command took over five minutes and when I tried to kill it my session froze.  I believe it's attributable to what Ashish Kumar Mehta wrote in another answer: `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ?` is a resource-intensive operation

Answer (score 20):

```sql
SELECT 
    sc.name +'.'+ ta.name TableName, SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
FROM 
    sys.tables ta
INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
    ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
    ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
ORDER BY SUM(pa.rows) DESC
```

Comment: Just wanted to note the reason for the "pa.index_id IN (1,0)" condition: it is to limit it to just one set of row counts for a table. More info here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/456062/352349

Comment: Think this is not including views. Other than that it works fine

Answer (score 17):

SQL Server 2005 or later gives quite a nice report showing table sizes - including row counts etc. It's in Standard Reports - and it is Disc Usage by Table.

Programmatically, there's a nice solution at:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/67624/

Comment: Without any admin rights this works well.

SELECT T.name AS [TABLE NAME], 
       I.rows AS [ROWCOUNT] 
FROM   sys.tables AS T 
       INNER JOIN sys.sysindexes AS I 
               ON T.object_id = I.id 
                  AND I.indid < 2 
ORDER  BY I.rows DESC

Comment: Years later, this answer and Ash's comment are what worked for me.  Rikin Patel's solution tied up my session, and other solutions exceeded my permissions.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLENAME`, since that is a resource intensive operation. One should use [**SQL Server Dynamic Management Views**](http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/RowCount_of_all_Tables_P1.html) or [**System Catalogs**](http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/RowCount_of_all_Tables_P2.html) to get the row count information for all tables in a database.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a dynamic SQL approach that also gives you the schema as well:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT
    @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ' UNION ALL ', '') +
        'SELECT
            ''' + s.name + ''' AS ''Schema'',
            ''' + t.name + ''' AS ''Table'',
            COUNT(*) AS Count
            FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
    FROM sys.schemas s
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    ORDER BY
        s.name,
        t.name

EXEC(@sql)
```

If needed, it would be trivial to extend this to run over all databases in the instance (join to `sys.databases`).

Answer (score 3):

I would make a minor change to Frederik's solution.  I would use the sp_spaceused system stored procedure which will also include data and index sizes.

```
declare c_tables cursor fast_forward for 
select table_name from information_schema.tables 

open c_tables 
declare @tablename varchar(255) 
declare @stmt nvarchar(2000) 
declare @rowcount int 
fetch next from c_tables into @tablename 

while @@fetch_status = 0 
begin 

    select @stmt = 'sp_spaceused ' + @tablename 

    exec sp_executesql @stmt

    fetch next from c_tables into @tablename 

end 

close c_tables 
deallocate c_tables
```

Answer (score 2):

select all rows from the information_schema.tables view, and issue a count(*) statement for each entry that has been returned from that view.

```
declare c_tables cursor fast_forward for
select table_name from information_schema.tables

open c_tables
declare @tablename varchar(255)
declare @stmt nvarchar(2000)
declare @rowcount int
fetch next from c_tables into @tablename

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin

    select @stmt = 'select @rowcount = count(*) from ' + @tablename

    exec sp_executesql @stmt, N'@rowcount int output', @rowcount=@rowcount OUTPUT

    print N'table: ' + @tablename + ' has ' + convert(nvarchar(1000),@rowcount) + ' rows'

    fetch next from c_tables into @tablename

end

close c_tables
deallocate c_tables
```

Comment: I know this is 13 years old at this point, but I'd also add the schema_name to this, and I'd query with that as well. `from ' + @tableschema  + '.' + @tablename;` If you partition your databases by schema that will actually be required.

Answer (score 1):

This is my favorite solution for SQL 2008 , which puts the results into a "TEST" temp table that I can use to sort and get the results that I need :

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(0) 
DROP TABLE #t;
CREATE TABLE #t 
( 
[name] NVARCHAR(128),
[rows] CHAR(11),
reserved VARCHAR(18), 
data VARCHAR(18), 
index_size VARCHAR(18),
unused VARCHAR(18)
) ;
INSERT #t EXEC sp_msForEachTable 'EXEC sp_spaceused ''?''' 
SELECT * INTO TEST FROM #t;
DROP TABLE #t;
SELECT  name, [rows], reserved, data, index_size, unused FROM TEST \
WHERE ([rows] > 0) AND (name LIKE 'XXX%')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT
          SUM(sdmvPTNS.row_count) AS [DBRows]
    FROM
          sys.objects AS sOBJ
          INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS sdmvPTNS
                ON sOBJ.object_id = sdmvPTNS.object_id
    WHERE 
          sOBJ.type = 'U'
          AND sOBJ.is_ms_shipped = 0
          AND sdmvPTNS.index_id < 2
    GO
```