# SQL-query that finds the table that contains most rows in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server

So as the title says i need a query that finds the table that contains most rows in my database.

I can show all my tables with this query:

```
select * from sys.tables
```

Or:

```
select *
from sysobjects
where xtype = 'U'
order by name
```

And all the indexes with this query:

```
select *
from sys.indexes
```

But how do i show the columns with most rows in the whole database?

Kind regards, Chris

Comment: [How to fetch the row count for all tables in a SQL SERVER database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221555/how-to-fetch-the-row-count-for-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use this query usually to sort all tables by rowcount:

```
USE DATABASENAME
SELECT t.NAME AS TableName, SUM(p.rows) AS RowCounts
FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
WHERE t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 AND i.index_id <= 1
GROUP BY t.NAME, i.object_id, i.index_id, i.name
ORDER BY SUM(p.rows) desc
```

If you want only the firts just add `TOP 1` after `SELECT`

--in reply to your comment----

```
WHERE 
 t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND --exclude Database Diagram tables like dtProperties
 i.OBJECT_ID > 255 AND  --exclude system-level tables
 i.index_id <= 1 -- avoid non clustered index
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but how do i check if the answer i get is correct?

Comment: @Chris `select count(*) from TABLENAME`

Comment: And i dont get this part: WHERE t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND i.object_id > 255 AND i.index_id <= 1 
Can you explain?

Comment: I get the same results with this query: 
select top 1 name, max(rows) as AmountOfRows from sys.sysindexes
group by name
order by max(rows) desc

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221555/how-to-fetch-the-row-count-for-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database), you can run the following to see the table with the highest row count:

```
CREATE TABLE #counts
(
    table_name varchar(255),
    row_count int
)

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable @command1='INSERT #counts (table_name, row_count) SELECT ''?'', COUNT(*) FROM ?'
SELECT TOP 1 table_name, row_count FROM #counts ORDER BY row_count DESC

DROP TABLE #counts
```

Comment: I dont want to create a table, I alredy have a database containing tables, in which i want find which table has got the most rows, by using a query. Thanks for helping

Comment: It's not actually creating a table in the database. It's creating a temporary, in-memory table that gets removed afterwards. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/ You need it because the `sp_MSForEachTable` function returns a result set on each iteration, so without it you'd have to look through them manually to find the largest row count.

Comment: The sp_MSForEachTable doesnt work "Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 7 Could not find stored procedure 'sp_MSForEachTable'."
Does it help that i have a column in sys.indexes that is rowcnt?

Comment: Is your DB character set case sensitive? Try writing `sp_MSforeachtable` (only MS is upper case)

Comment: You can use sys.indexes, I would guess it's a little faster as it doesn't have to scan the table, but the row count reflects uncommitted data and can be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use this query to get no duplicates in table names:

```
Use[DataBase_Name]
select max(i.rows) as recordCounts,t.name as table_name, 
SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) as schema_name from sysindexes i
inner join sys.tables t
on i.id=object_id
group by t.name, SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)
```