# the query "select num_rows from user_tables" not returning the rows count even though i have rows

Tags: sql, oracle11g

The below query

```
select num_rows from user_tables;
```

in SQL not returning the rows count ,showing as empty like below even though i have two rows in one of user table .

```
SQL> select num_rows from user_tables;

  NUM_ROWS
----------
```

can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
select COUNT(*) from user_tables;
```

OR

```
Select COUNT(table_name) from user_tables
```

`num_rows` returns no.of rows value is updated by `DBMS_STATS`. So it does not contain the current number of rows in the table but an approximation calculated the last time `DBMS_STATS` was run.

---

**Update** : For counting all the rows in  all tables in database:

**1.** Better way:

```
`select table_name, num_rows from user_tables;`
```

**OR Alternatively**

**2.** using function(not recommended)

```
create or replace
function get_rows( p_tname in varchar2 ) return number
as
    l_columnValue    number default NULL;
begin
    execute immediate
       'select count(*)
          from ' || p_tname INTO l_columnValue;

    return l_columnValue;
end;
```

For running function after creating using above code:

```
 select user, table_name,
           get_rows( user||'.'||table_name) cnt
      from user_tables
```

Please note this is for oracle. For Sql server refer :
[How to fetch the row count for all tables in a SQL SERVER database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221555/how-to-fetch-the-row-count-for-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database)

Comment: select COUNT(*) from user_tables; will return the count of tables in user_tables, not returning the row count.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` returns row count for the table. What do you mean by `count of tables in user_tables`? Is `user_tables` is database ???, then `select anything from user_tables` mustn't work

Comment: Count(*) of user_tables not returning row count for me. If i try select table_name from user_tables, it showing the all user tables list. So, count(*) of user_tables is not for returning row count of all tables of user_tables.

Comment: Count(*) must work. Anyways try `Select COUNT(table_name) from user_tables`

Comment: I tried , but it returning the count of tables , not the rows. See the queires i ran and output.  SQL> select * from cell;

 ID NAME        CRC
---------- -------------------------------- ----------
  1 test1       234
  2 test2       235

SQL> Select COUNT(table_name) from user_tables;

COUNT(TABLE_NAME)
-----------------
  3

Comment: Actually, i have 3 tables, and in one table called cell having only two rows. But whatever query you suggested returning the table count not the row count.

Comment: for which table you want count, your question seems to be unclear? For `cell`, its like `select count(*) from cell`.

Comment: No. I want count of all rows of all tables in the user_tables list

Comment: Got it, you want count of all of the tables in the database. Am I correct? Updating answer for that

Comment: SQL> select * from cell;

 ID NAME        CRC
---------- -------------------------------- ----------
  1 test1       234
  2 test2       235

SQL> select table_name, num_rows from user_tables; 

TABLE_NAME    NUM_ROWS
------------------------------ ----------
PUBSMARKERGENE
POLYAPREDICT
CELL

Comment: I used above query you suggested. But nothing it showing the above ouput i am getting