# Loop through result set of mysql in Bash

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a simple bash script. I wish to get an exact count of the number of rows in each table of the database.

```
#!/bin/bash

TABLES_OLD=$( mysql -u user -ppassword MySchema --batch --skip-column-names -e"SHOW TABLES FROM MySchema" )

for table in "${TABLES_OLD[@]}"
do
    QUERY="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${table}"
    echo "${QUERY}"
done
```

The script prints:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table 1
Table2
Table3
Table4
etc...
```

Clearly this is not what I want, and I don't even understand how what is happening is possible. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add output of `mysql -u user -ppassword MySchema --batch --skip-column-names -e"SHOW TABLES FROM MySchema"` to your question.

Comment: `TABLES_OLD` is not an array. It is a string. `tables_old=($(mysql ....))` would make an array split on words (but would also glob metacharacters, etc.). The correct way to loop over line-by-line data from a stream is explained in [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this, put the tables into an array then loop thru the results
db_host='host'
db_user='user'
db_pass='password'
db='your_db'

read -ra var_id <<< $(mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -p$db_pass $db -sse "show tables from $db")
for i in "${var_id[@]}"; 
    do
results=$(mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -p$db_pass $db -sse "select count(*)from $i")
echo "$i $results"

done
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :

```
#/bin/bash
mysql -u user-ppassword -e "SELECT table_name, table_rows
                     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                     WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_data_base_name';"
```

Comment: This does not seem to give me the exact count on many tables. It's really close though.

Comment: You might wish to have a look [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65216/need-help-to-understand-how-information-schema-tables-get-updated)

Comment: @LeviX : Youmay also wish to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2221898/1620779)

Answer (score -1):

Replace `echo` with `eval`

The code will be

```
#!/bin/bash

TABLES_OLD=$( mysql -u user -ppassword MySchema --batch --skip-column-names -e"SHOW TABLES FROM MySchema" )

for table in "${TABLES_OLD[@]}"
do
    QUERY="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${table}"
    eval "${QUERY}"
done
```

Comment: No, this won't help. This isn't *at all* the issue and isn't *at all* a good idea.