# Django model count() with caching

Tags: django, database, python-2.7, caching, prometheus

I have an Django application with Apache Prometheus monitoring and model called `Sample`.

I want to monitor Sample.objects.count() metric 
and cache this value for concrete time interval 
to avoid costly COUNT(*) queries in database.

From this tutorial 
https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#custom-collectors
i read that i need to write custom collector.

What is best approach to achieve this? 
Is there any way in django to 
get `Sample.objects.count()` cached value and update it after K seconds?
I also use Redis in my application. Should i store this value there?
Should i make separate thread to update `Sample.objects.count()` cache value?

Comment: I think your question is of value to a lot of users not just those using prometheus, so I hope you don't mind the edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First thing to note is that you don't really need to cache the result of a count(*) query.

Though different RDBMS handle count operations differently, they are slow across the board for large tables. But one thing they have in common is that there is an alternative to SELECT COUNT(*) provided by the RDBMS which is in fact a cached result. Well sort of.

You haven't mentioned what your RDBMS is so let's see how it is in the popular ones used wtih Django

### mysql

Provided you have a primary key on your table and you are using MyISAM. SELECT COUNT(*) is really fast on mysql and scales well. But chances are that you are using Innodb. And that's the right storage engine for various reasons. Innodb is transaction aware and can't handle COUNT(*) as well as MyISAM and the query slows down as the table grows.

the count query on a table with 2M records took 0.2317 seconds. The following query took 0.0015 seconds

```
SELECT table_rows FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name='for_count';
```

but it reported a value of 1997289 instead of 2 million but close enough!

So you don't need your own caching system.

### Sqlite

Sqlite COUNT(*) queries aren't really slow but it doesn't scale either. As the table size grows the speed of the count query slows down. Using a table similar to the one used in mysql, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM for_count` required 0.042 seconds to complete.

There isn't a short cut. The `sqlite_master` table does not provide row counts. Neither does `pragma table_info`

You need your own system to cache the result of SELECT COUNT(*)

### Postgresql

Despite being the most feature rich open source RDBMS, postgresql isn't good at handling count(*), it's slow and doesn't scale very well. In other words, no different from the poor relations!

The count query took 0.194 seconds on postgreql. On the other hand the following query took 0.003 seconds.

```
SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'for_count'
```

You don't need your own caching system.

### SQL Server

The COUNT query on SQL server took 0.160 seconds on average but it fluctuated rather wildly. For all the databases discussed here the first count(*) query was rather slow but the subsequent queries were faster because the file was cached by the operating system.

I am not an expert on SQL server so before answering this question, I didn't know how to look up the row count using schema info. I found this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221555/how-to-fetch-the-row-count-for-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database) helpfull. One of them I tried produced the result in 0.004 seconds

```
SELECT t.name, s.row_count from sys.tables t
JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
ON t.object_id = s.object_id
AND t.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
AND t.name ='for_count'
AND s.index_id = 1
```

You dont' need your own caching system.

### Integrate into Django

As can be seen, all databases considered except sqlite provide a built in 'Cached query count' There isn't a need for us to create one of our own. It's a simple matter of creating a customer manager to make use of this functionality.

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):

    def quick_count(self):
        from django.db import connection
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("""SELECT table_rows FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_name='for_count'""")

         row = cursor.fetchone()
         return row[0]

class Sample(models.Model):
    ....
    objects = CustomManager()
```

The above example is for postgresql, but the same thing can be used for mysql or sql server by simply changing the query into one of those listed above.

### Prometheus

How to plug this into django prometheus? I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: "The above example is for postgresql" - no it isn't :}  there is no `information_schema` in postgresql.

Comment: haha, my bad.  but still confusingly, you used a different example than your answer about postgresql (`reltuples`)...

Comment: FYI, from the manager, you can retrieve the table name with: `self.model._meta.db_table`

Comment: WARNING! reltuples is an estimated count not an exact count. If you need an accurate count then you do need caching https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate#:~:text=reltuples%20%3A,commands%20such%20as%20CREATE%20INDEX%20.

Comment: @abaldwin99 you completely forgot that caching is also not 100% accurate

Comment: @e4c5 If we save the result from a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query and bust the saved result within a transaction whenever rows are inserted/deleted then it would be an accurate count.

Comment: @abaldwain caching doesn't give you an accurate count either so what's the point ?

Answer (score 1):

A custom collector that returns the previous value if it's not too old and fetches otherwise would be the way to go. I'd keep it all in-process.

If you're using MySQL you might want to look at the collectors the mysqld_exporter offers as there's some for table size that should be cheaper.

Comment: Why Redis is not good idea? What framework is best for prometheus custom collectors? Is Flask good solution for this problem? Is there any way to create prometheus custom collector inside django application?