# SQL get name of table or view currently being queried

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a long list of tables / views, and I just need a count of the records and the name of the object being queried, for example...

```
SELECT COUNT(*), TableOrViewName FROM TableOrView

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(*), TableOrViewName FROM TableOrView

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(*), TableOrViewName FROM TableOrView
```

Comment: So add the name into the queries `SELECT`: `N'TableOrView' AS TableOrViewName` here, (obviously) `N'TableOrView'` is the *actual* name of the table or `VIEW`. Though, if you want just a `COUNT` of the rows in the tables, there are alternative ways to do this without using `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Isn't it a job for Sql Server Profiler ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16 You may also find interesting solutions here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan-in-sql-server

Comment: For tables and indexed views, consider using DMVs to get the row count if it doesn't need to be transactionally consistent. This will avoid full scans of the tables.

Comment: See [Bad habits : Counting rows the hard way](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way)

Comment: @Larnu, I would need to go through every query to add that, I was hoping there was a function or variable I could use.  I could just generate this dynamically but wanted to check first.

Comment: You would, which is why I said there are alternative ways; see the above link, @ChristianPhillips .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch the row count for all tables in a SQL SERVER database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221555/how-to-fetch-the-row-count-for-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database)

Comment: A trivial search for "sql server count rows in all tables" will find many suggestions. Refer to the suggestion involving the system tables from Keng

Comment: I will change the query to use DMV, this is a "one off" query.

Comment: @SMor, I don't want all the tables, only a subset of them in different schemas.

Comment: Insert your list of tables\views to temp table and then use it with the query from @Larnu comment