Output any table in a database that has rows using SQL
I want to be able to output any table that has a rowcount > 0 in SQL database. So in other words if the database has 100 tables I want to be able to know which tables have rows
I have tried the following:
 SELECT table_name
 FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE table_schema = 'your_database_name' 
 AND table_rows > 0;

But it says table_rows is an invalid column
How can I do this?

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221555/how-to-fetch-the-row-count-for-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database

When you say "any table", do you actually want "system tables" to be included in the output or just all "user tables"???

You can get the row count of the tables from the partitions table.
So you will join to this table and check which tables have a row count > 0.
If you want to see the row count of those tables, you will do following:
SELECT 
  t.name AS table_name,
  SUM(p.rows) AS row_count
FROM 
  sys.schemas s
  JOIN sys.tables t 
    ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
  JOIN sys.partitions p 
    ON p.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE
  s.name = 'your_schema_name' 
  AND p.index_id <= 1
GROUP BY t.name
HAVING SUM(p.rows) > 0;

If you don't need this information, but simply want to get the table names, you can skip one JOIN and rather use a subquery to improve the performance:
SELECT 
  t.name AS table_name
FROM 
  sys.schemas s
  JOIN sys.tables t 
    ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
  s.name = 'your_schema_name' 
  AND t.object_id IN 
    (SELECT p.object_id 
     FROM sys.partitions p 
     WHERE 
       p.index_id <= 1 AND 
       p.rows > 0);

See this sample fiddle

Might wanna add p.index_id <=1 just for prudency

No need to retrieve the info for all partitions and sum them as the presence of any non empty partition is enough. So possible alternative is https://dbfiddle.uk/nXIwz9_W

@MartinSmith True, this would be clever in case they don't care about the exact row count, added this option.

There's a lot of hidden power in the intrinsic functions of SQL Server.  When the "object_id()" column is present in a dmv and a "database_id" is not, such as it is in sys.partitions, there's no need to join to sys.tables for such things IF the objects are in the "current" database in SSMS or any other app.
The names and the use of the Microsoft functions are self-evident.
--===== Find all tables in the current database that have rows.
 SELECT TableName = CONCAT(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id),'.',OBJECT_NAME(object_id))
   FROM sys.partitions
  WHERE index_id <= 1 --0 = "Heap", 1 = Clustered Index - Can't exist at same time.
    AND rows     >  0
;

Here are the references to the Microsoft Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partitions-transact-sql
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-name-transact-sql
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-schema-name-transact-sql
If you want to exclude the system table names, the following will do...
--===== Find all "user generated" tables in the current database that have rows.
 SELECT TableName = CONCAT(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id),'.',OBJECT_NAME(object_id))
   FROM sys.partitions
  WHERE index_id <= 1 --0 = "Heap", 1 = Clustered Index - Can't exist at same time.
    AND rows     >  0
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id,'IsMSShipped') = 0 -- Not created during installation
;

Here's the link for the OBJECTPROPERTY() function.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/objectproperty-transact-sql

Should probably add a GROUP BY object_id to avoid calling these functions multiple times for the same objects in the event they are partitioned (and returning as many rows in the results as the table partition count)

To meet the exact request, I agree.  As a sidebar for me, I'd probably like to know if it's partitioned and that would do it.
